# Why can't I get a message from telegram in my terminal

Tags: python, event-handling, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to make an application in Python. In the application I need a function to read some messages that are send in telegram.

It connects to telegram no problem, gets a list of available channels -> ok. Want to receive a message from the channel into my terminal, nothing..

I tried to connect with telethon and I do not receive a message with the following code:

```
# Function to start the Telegram

client
    async def start_telegram_client():
        global telegram_client
        try:
            phone_number = simpledialog.askstring("Phone Number", "Enter your phone number:")
            if not phone_number:
                return
    
            session_name = 'Session'  # Change 'anon_unique' to a unique session name
            telegram_client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)
            await telegram_client.start(phone=phone_number, code_callback=ask_code)
            lbl_telegram_status.config(text="Connected to Telegram")
    
            # Fetch and update the channel list
            await update_channel_list()
    
            # Enable the 'Choose Channel' button and the dropdown menu
            btn_choose_channel.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
            channel_menu.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
           
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error connecting to Telegram: {e}")
            lbl_telegram_status.config(text="Connection Error")
            
    # Function to ask for the Telegram code
    async def ask_code():
        return simpledialog.askstring("Verification Code", "Enter the verification code:")
    
    async def get_channels(client):
        channels = []
        async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
            if isinstance(dialog.entity, Channel):
                channel_id = int(f"-100{dialog.entity.id}")
                channel_name = dialog.name
                channels.append((channel_name, channel_id))
                print(f"Fetched channel: {channel_name} with ID: {channel_id}")
        return channels
    
    async def update_channel_list():
        global channel_options, channel_menu, channel_dict
        channels = await get_channels(telegram_client)
        channel_options.set('Select a Channel')
        menu = channel_menu["menu"]
        menu.delete(0, "end")
        channel_dict = {}
        for name, _id in channels:
            channel_dict[name] = _id
            menu.add_command(label=name, command=lambda value=name: channel_options.set(value))
    
    # Choose Channel to Listen
    def choose_channel():
        global selected_channel, channel_dict
        selected_channel_name = channel_options.get()
        if selected_channel_name != 'Select a Channel':
            selected_channel_id = channel_dict[selected_channel_name]
            lbl_telegram_status.config(text=f"Copying from {selected_channel_name}")
            telegram_client.remove_event_handler(handle_new_message)
            telegram_client.add_event_handler(handle_new_message, events.NewMessage(chats=[selected_channel_id]))
            print(f"Event handler registered for channel ID: {selected_channel_id}")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Please select a channel")
    
    # Define the event handler function
    @events.register(events.NewMessage)
    async def handle_new_message(event):
        print(f"New message received: {event.raw_text}")
        
    def run_async_loop(loop):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_forever()
```